# Unresolved class name using passport-slack node library

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, slack-api

I am attempting to use the [passport-slack](https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack) library, and am very new to node.js (though not programming in general).

In the readme is the following example code:

```
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
     clientID: CLIENT_ID,
     clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
     scope: "users:write"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
     User.findOrCreate({ SlackId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
       return done(err, user);
     });
  }
));
```

The part that confuses me is the ***SlackStrategy*** class identifier — I don’t see it exported from any of the code in passport-slack, and I can’t figure out how I am supposed to resolve it. I am doing a:

```
var passport-slack = require(‘passport-slack’);
```

at the top of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var SlackStrategy = require('passport-slack').Strategy;
```

Looking through:
https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack/blob/master/lib/passport-slack/index.js

It seems to be exported as `Strategy` and not `SlackStrategy` (must be just what the dev named the variable).